# Open other Activities on Gallery

Tags: android, eclipse, onclick, listener, gallery

I have a gallery with images. I want to open other activities every time I click an image from the gallery. I'm having a hard time with Onclicklisteners/onitemclicklisteners.

here's my code.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

private Integer[]  pics = { R.drawable.school, R.drawable.gradeview, R.drawable.history, R.drawable.schoolorg };

private ImageView imageView;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



    Gallery gallery = (Gallery) findViewById(R.id.gallery1);
    gallery.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
    imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    gallery.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            //
            // I DON'T KNOW WHAT TO PUT HERE
            // I DON'T KNOW WHAT TO PUT HERE

        }
    });

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
    private Context context;
    int imageBackground;

    public ImageAdapter(Context context){
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return pics.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return arg0;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return arg0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int arg0, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
        imageView.setImageResource(pics[arg0]);
        return imageView;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

to open other activity, you can simpy user intent,

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setClass(getApplicationContext(), YOUR_NEW_ACTIVITY.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

but make sure, your new activity must be declared in manifest like:

```
<activity android:name=".YOUR_NEW_ACTIVITY"></activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    gallery.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Intent intent =new Intent(MainActvity.this,ImageShow.class);//Class name to redirect
intent.putExtra("Image",pics[arg2]); //Image url to send to the next to show image
startActivity(intent);
this.finish();


        }
    });
```